# How do you get knitr PDf on an .rmd file to affect the title parameters?

Tags: r, latex, knitr, r-markdown

My .rmd file now reads:

```
---
title: "My title"
author: "Fix"
date: "March 28, 2016"
output: pdf_document
---
```

And I'm looking to have it say something like:

```
---
title: "My title"
author: "Fix"
date: "March 28, 2016"
thanks: "Everybody that helped me!"
output: pdf_document
---
```

so that the thanks are included in the title page of the document...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easier way is to use latex command `\thanks`:

```
---
title: "My title\\thanks{I am grateful to everybody that helped me!}"
---
```

It will output thanks as a footnote to the title. If you are unhappy with the format, you can also [change your latex template](http://pandoc.org/README.html#using-variables-in-templates) and redefine `\maketitle`, for instance using `usepackage{titling}`.

Comment: Thanks! I tried a bunch of things and also tried changing the template, but this is by far the simples route.